# CoPilot behind Zscaler - Error on ghost text request: (FetchError) unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I installed CoPilot extension in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Edition on Windows 10 on my company computer in my home office. My company computer is shipped with Zscaler which is installed by my corporate IT. The Zscaler tunnel is enabled so that I can access my intranet.

Given this environment I tried to test CoPilot free edition so I followed the installation instructions from [Getting started with GitHub Copilot](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/using-github-copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot?tool=visualstudio)

Unfortunately I get this error

```
[ERROR] [ghostText] [2024-01-10T16:46:40.022Z] Error on ghost text request: (FetchError) unable to get local issuer certificate
```

[image]

Obviously it has something to do with Zscaler, I am not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error as follows:

- Browse to URL https://copilot-proxy.githubusercontent.com/v1/engines/copilot-codex with chrome then export the Zscaler Root CA certificate to a file e.g. **C:\Data\CoPilot\CA\Zscaler Root CA.pem** as shown below:
  [image]
- Define new user or system environment variable **NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS** and set its value to the exported Zscaler certificate as shown below:
  [image]
- Restart Visual Studio, start typing some code and check the CoPilot output
  [image]

Comment: how did you know to do these steps? because I'm having the same issue and these instructions are not solving it

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean?